# How do I remove dark areas from my mesh?

Tags: modeling

I am doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNbAmJ3eubo) tutorial to model an iPhone. One of the things I try to work on is my ability to judge wether a mesh is ok or not ok. Now I think that these parts are not ok

[image]

[image]

So ... is there something wrong or not ? I already tried moving vertices but could not make these "dark areas" go.

Also ... at about 10:30 min of the tutorial the "tutor" feels the edge of the iphone should be more "rounded" and repairs that. I thought my edge is ok ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some of your vertices got moved arround, maybe by using "proportional editing/scaling".

[image]

Cleaned up version:

[image]

Work around:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks. how did you do the repair action (since that is also what I want to learn) ?

Comment: I've just added pictures showing the steps I made to repair your model.

Comment: You could press `Alt`+`.` (coma) to change Pivot Point to *Active element*, select vertices from the phone back and one which is located correctly as the last one (so it to be active) and scale by Y axis. This would let you skip copying values.